# Create delay within the Web Service API using Thread.Sleep or Stopwatch

Tags: web-services, iis, stopwatch

I want to put a delay within my web service app, between 2 procedure calls. I am using *Thread.Sleep(60000);* and it works well on Debug but when I Publish it, the app seems to ignore the wait. I replaced it essentially with the same logic:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; ;i++)
{
   if ( i % 100000 == 0)
   {
      sw.Stop();
      if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 60000) // Has it been a minute?
      {
         break;
      }
      else
      {
         sw.Start();
      }
   }
}
```

but I get the same results and does not apply delay.

Are there any other ways to implement wait on the Web Service app? Is there any setting on IIS that should be change to allow the wait? TIA

Comment: "I want to put a delay within my web service app, between 2 procedure calls." Explain more on that. Meanwhile, `Thread.Sleep` should be forbidden, while `Stopwatch` is not for the purpose at all.

Comment: Hi Lex, I am sending 2  MML commands via SSH client to fetch a large data. Command1 orders the data while command2 prints the data in the SSH session. To assure there's is data fetched by the SSH client, delay between the commands should happen.

Comment: Please update the question to include that, as that's the true question you have, not the code above. If your goal is to properly implement the functionality, then you should find a way to queue the operations (ordering the data, and printing them), and there are a lot of possibilities (message queues and so on). However, no good design would use `Thread.Sleep` or `Stopwatch` and wait for a fixed period of time.